# Instantiate dynamic text in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

When I collect a power-up in my game I want to instantiate dynamic text (e.g. "Missile" or "Shield") at the power-up's location but my code doesn't work.

This is my function (I admit it 's a bit messy):

```
public Text upgradeTxtPrefab;

void ShowUpgradeTxt (string _upgradeTxt) {

        // find canvas
        GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");

        Text tempUpgradeTxt = (Text)Instantiate (upgradeTxtPrefab);

        tempUpgradeTxt.fontSize = 24;

        tempUpgradeTxt.transform.position = this.transform.position;

        tempUpgradeTxt.transform.SetParent (canvas.transform, false);

        upgradeTxtPrefab.text = _upgradeTxt;

}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: The text doesn't show up.

Comment: so no gameobject is created? the text doesnt change? please be specific

Comment: The game objects are created but I can't see the text on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not setting the right text. You're setting the text for `upgradeTxtPrefab` but you instantiated `tempUpgradeTxt`

It should be `tempUpgradeTxt.text = _upgradeTxt;`

Comment: I changed it like you said but I still can't see the text.

Comment: At runtime when the Text object is created, check and see if in the inspector, does the text field contain text?

Comment: Ok. The text is there. There seems to be a problem with the position. In the inspector it says x = -563 and y = -906. They are not on the visible screen. How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe try setting the position equal to the canvas's position and see where it puts it? I would also remove the line where you are changing the prefab's position.

Comment: I deleted the two code lines with the position and updated my code. The position is still weird and I don't know what causes it.

Comment: Also, make sure your text field is big enough to hold your text. If your text is too big, it will not render it.

Comment: It renders the text. I already checked this. When I enter 0 in both position-fields (x and y) I can see the text in the center of the screen.